# How to share my PC's(Windows 10) internet to my iPhone 7 via Bluetooth?

Tags: windows, internet, bluetooth, hotspot, tethering

I have a PC (Windows 10), which has internet. I don't have Wifi internet. So, is it possible to share my PC's internet to my iPhone 7 via Bluetooth connection?

Comment: It is probably not possible using Bluetooth at the moment, but I may be wrong. You can probably do it with both Wifi ([Sharing Windows 10 Internet connection via LAN and Wifi simultaneously](https://superuser.com/q/1343113/173513)) and USB cable ([iPhone Connecting to Internet Using Windows PC’s Network through USB Cable](https://www.systutorials.com/136003/iphone-connecting-internet-using-windows-pc-network-through-usb-cable/)).

Answer (score 2):

On Windows 10 Mobile Hotspot under Settings, start your hotspot using Bluetooth. On your iPhone under Bluetooth devices try to connect to your PC, if the option is unavailable unpair both devices and pair them again.

[image: Bluetooth Hotspot]

Comment: What exactly are the requirements for Mobile Hotspot to be offered?  Please edit your question to provide specific details with regards to that.  I was unable to find Mobile Hotspot.  Please note, I don't actually have the problem the author had, this comment is only being submitted so you will improve the quality of your answer.  Please do not respond to my comment, with another comment.  Just improve the answer.