# Sharing Windows 10 Internet connection via LAN and Wifi simultaneously

Tags: networking, windows-10, connection-sharing, ics, internet-sharing

I have the following scenario:

[image]

I am trying to share "Wi-Fi"'s internet connection via both "Ethernet 3" and "Wi-Fi 2".

In the situation shown in the screenshot, ICS (Internet Connection Sharing) is enabled from "Wi-Fi" to "Ethernet 3" and the mobile hotspot is enabled at the same time.

However, the internet on devices connected to the hotspot is not working. It gets deactivated as soon as ICS to "Ethernet 3" is enabled. I somehow see that this is due to how ICS works between two network adapters on windows, but I would like to know whether there is a workaround.

This is my university's eduroam connection, so I don't have access to the router.

Comment: Do you have the ICS set up [the way pointed out at superuser.com](https://superuser.com/a/1090596/921727)?

Comment: I have seen that answer, but I'm not sure how this applies to hotspots. Just sharing a connection to "Wi-Fi 2" doesn't create a hotspot yet. And the virtual adapter "Local Area Connection" doesn't have any bridging option.